# How to get attribute value of mutiple selection in the Owebia shipping method

Tags: magento

How to get attribute value of multiple selection in the Owebia shipping method?

My Owebia code below:

```
{count items where array_match_any(product.attribute.**shipping_restriction**.**value**', array('AU','NZ','AU,NZ'))}
```

But,I can't get the attribute value,I only can get the id num of attribute,

1. **shipping_restriction** is my custom attribute,which has a multiple selected menu.
2. It just return the index num,not 'NZ' or 'AU',it just return the index num,not 'NZ' or 'AU'
3. If I have changed the multiple selected menu into single selection,it could get right value. Like 'NZ' or 'AU',and not index num.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by using following syntax to get value.

```
product.attribute.*.value
```

Where * is attribute placeholder.

Reference: http://www.owebia.com/os2/en/doc#formulas_variables_product